# Large dataset processing using Mule ESB from database: how to update the processed records based on certain batch size?

Tags: jdbc, mule, esb

I have a large set of records to be processed eg: 100,000 records. My use case has 4 steps:

1. pick the records from database table using jdbc inbound adapter
2. convert the record to xml format
3. post the message to the queue
4. then update the same record with some status flag as it has been processed so that it will not be picked again

I don't want to pick all the records from table at one shot for processing: is there a way so that pick in some batches and don't want to update table for one record? Is there any option of bulk/batch update at batch level?

Or is there any other better way to approach this use case? Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the SQL select query to return only N records (like `LIMIT 100` or equivalent) with a where clause that excludes the already processed records based on the status flag.

Comment: Instead of using a status flag you can save the last processed id (anywhere you want) and keep updating this record until you process them all.. your choice

Comment: So you would select the last processed id first, then select the batch, then update the last processed id? That sounds good but how do you do that with a JDBC inbound endpoint that regularly polls the database for records? I guess you'd use a `<poll>` router or `quartz` endpoint then?

Comment: Hi David, But how would the other records

Comment: @DavidDossot yeah, i think so. Just suggested that if he doesn't have the status flag column or dont want to create one.

Comment: @user2044172 A word to the wise is not sufficient in this case :P i think that there is something missing :P

Comment: @David,
 Using rownum is my initial thought But how the other records will be processed I mean let's say I have 1000 records and I use rownum < 101,then how the other 900 records will processed. Do I need to configure a poller or is there any other way.If poller what should be poller time because if I say configure poller time as 2min but if the first set of records still processing even after 2 min, In that case does processing of next set of records wait till the processing of first set of records or irrespective of poller time or it simply start processing of the next set of records.

Comment: @David,How to update the status flag per 100 records.I'm getting one one record in each step.Is it like I need to write a custom java component so that I keep primary key in some java collection and once the size is 100 issue an update or is there an in built support to update at a particular batch size.

Comment: take a look on quartz transport

Comment: @Jonfornari,there is an poller support for jdbc inbound component,Quartz transport also more or less does the same thing right Any idea about updating records in batches or one update after 100 messages.

Comment: Yes, if processing can be slower than the polling frequency, there's a risk to select the same record again. Otherwise, with the right where clause in the select query, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: @David,Any thoughts about updating records in batches or one update after 100 messages.Somehow I feel poller is not the best option,because <br>
 1)if my processing time is more than polling frequency there is a risk of picking same record,no reliability in this approach.<br/>
 2)if my processing time less than polling frequency then need to wait till the polling frequency time is complete to process 
the next set of records,it's not time effective in this approach.

Comment: I agree with you: it's probably better you review your current plan to use a JDBC inbound endpoint, because it's a polling one. So, what could be a good alternative trigger for starting this batch processing?

Comment: @David,Any thoughts about updating records in batches or one update with primary keys in clause(comma separated) after 100 messages.
 while I'm looping over messages I would like to store the value of a certain xml node temporarily so that I will append those values
 with comma and then after certain batch size I will update once,But where I can store temporarily is my Question I tried session varibale it gets erased every time I loop in.Are there anything like flow variable that can serve my purpose.

Comment: You could Spring-config a cache (like EHCache) or a concurrent hashmap and use it as your state store.